# Ransackable Attributes for has many relationship columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

I want to display has_many relationship columns in ransackable attributes list. So that I can display them in the dropdown.

I have a member model

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships


 def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
  if auth_object == 'admin'
    super
  else
    super & ['first_name', 'last_name', 'license_number', 'memberships_membership_number_cont']
  end
 end
```

And membership model has some columns like membership_number which is unique and a string. Now in the dropdown of members listing page I want to provide membership_number, so that user can select membership_number from the dropdown and enter a value to search the respective member.

Any suggestions?

The dropdown I am taking about is:

[image]

*PS: In the screenshot you may be looking for a dropdown for contains all/contain any ie options dropdown. I made is just one only  contains any. Thats why its not visible.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the `ransackable_attributes` method in associated model for custom searchable attributes of that model. So your `Membership` model should be something like:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member
  ...

  def self.ransackable_attributes(auth_object = nil)
    ['membership_number', ...]
  end
end
```

And specify `associations` in ranssack form like:

```
<%= f.condition_fields do |c| %>
  <%= c.attribute_fields do |a| %>
    <%= a.attribute_select associations: [:memberships] %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @manjo2411 - thanks a lot for your tip. suppose memberships have many :bonuses. how can I search a field in the bonus model by ammending the associations hash you've made above?